# Jest - Assert that a mocked functions callback is called

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to achieve full coverage on this function but cannot seem to mock function so that it calls the `onSuccess` callback

**Code**

```
export const handleDelete = (action) => {
  const { id, type, actions } = action;

  actions.dispatch(
    actions.openDialog(`delete${type}`, Dialog, {
      onSuccess: () => {
        actions.dispatch(actions.thunk(id));
        actions.notify(`${type} deleted`, {
          variant: 'success',
        });
      },
      body: `Are you sure you want to delete this ${type}?`,
      title: `Delete ${type}`,
      confirm: 'Delete',
      cancel: 'Cancel',
      danger: true,
    })
  );
};
```

**Unit Test:**

```
  it('should handle delete', () => {
    const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
    const mockOnSuccess = jest.fn();
    const mockOpenDialog = jest.fn(() => ({
      onSuccess: mockOnSuccess,
    }));
    const mockAction = {
      id: 1,
      type: 'example',
      actions: {
        dispatch: mockDispatch,
        openDialog: mockOpenDialog,
      },
    };

    handleDelete(mockAction);

    expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockOpenDialog).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

**Coverage:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
export const handleDelete = (action) => {
  const { id, type, actions } = action;
  const Dialog = 'Dialog';

  actions.dispatch(
    actions.openDialog(`delete${type}`, Dialog, {
      onSuccess: () => {
        actions.dispatch(actions.thunk(id));
        actions.notify(`${type} deleted`, {
          variant: 'success',
        });
      },
      body: `Are you sure you want to delete this ${type}?`,
      title: `Delete ${type}`,
      confirm: 'Delete',
      cancel: 'Cancel',
      danger: true,
    }),
  );
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { handleDelete } from './';

describe('64803187', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const action = {
      id: '1',
      type: 'user',
      actions: {
        dispatch: jest.fn(),
        openDialog: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((type, dialog, options) => {
          options.onSuccess();
          return { type: 'OPEN_DIALOG' };
        }),
        notify: jest.fn(),
        thunk: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({ type: 'DELETE_USER_SUCCESS' }),
      },
    };
    handleDelete(action);
    expect(action.actions.dispatch).toBeCalledWith({ type: 'OPEN_DIALOG' });
    expect(action.actions.openDialog).toBeCalledWith('deleteuser', 'Dialog', {
      onSuccess: expect.any(Function),
      body: `Are you sure you want to delete this user?`,
      title: `Delete user`,
      confirm: 'Delete',
      cancel: 'Cancel',
      danger: true,
    });
    expect(action.actions.dispatch).toBeCalledWith({ type: 'DELETE_USER_SUCCESS' });
    expect(action.actions.notify).toBeCalledWith('user deleted', { variant: 'success' });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64803187/index.test.ts
  64803187
    ✓ should pass (8ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.267s, estimated 13s
```